# Is there a way to use hitTestObject between two classes in ActionScript3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I've got this game I've been working on and I wanted to test if my Car Class was hitting my Toad Class. I tried and I got errors like "Call to a possibly undefined method hitTestObject through a reference with static type Class".
So basically, I don't won't to use instances because it wouldn't be possible to program all of them separately. This is what I've been trying to do...

```
//document class,
if (theToad.hitTestObject(myBlueCar)) {
    trace("It's working!");
}
//theToad is the name of a class and so is myBlueCar
```

So when I run this I get that same "Call to a possibly..." error. Please, I am semi-new to all this and if anyone knows how to get around this it would be most appreciated.

Comment: You should at least post a sample of your code...

Comment: I updated it. It was my first time posting here...

Answer (score 0):

> "Call to a possibly undefined method hitTestObject through a reference with static type Class

Because you need create instances of your `Car` and `Toad` classes.
I assume you are doing it in this way:

```
Car.hitTestObject(Toad); 
//But you must create instances
var car: Car = new Car();
var toad: Toad = new Toad();
if(car.hitTestObject(toad)){
    trace("poor toad :(");
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks but where to I create these variables and do I test them in the document class? If so how will it know what I'm talking about , like won't it say undefined property "toad".

Comment: As a flash newcomer, It's ok if you will work with document class. To define `Toad` and `Car`, create movieclips in the library and [export them for ActionScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7fee.html).

Comment: Ok I did every thing you said but I wanted to be able to reuse cars without having to program them all which is why I needed them to test between classes. In the game their is a lot of cars so I need to be able to test them all against the toad, can you help?

Comment: Just create multiple If statements inside your hittest Function. Or you can add them all to an array and create a For loop which is the more advanced method but going the easy route the If statements is the best way to go

Comment: Could you post an example of the array method, I don't quite follow... I guess you would hitTest the two arrays after creation. But anyway in ideal world I like this, say I have a class called Toad and one called Car, I want to go if (Car.hitTestObject(Toad)) but of course that doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Objects are added through code and are not on the stage you would do this:

You need to create the instances and initiate them in your MainClass like so:

```
Private var toad:theToad;
Private var car:theBlueCar;
```

Then in your constructor function initiate them like so:

```
toad = new theToad();
car = new theBlueCar();
```

Then the Hittest in your enterFrame Event Function like so:

```
private function checkCarHitToad():void
{

  if(car.hitTestObject(toad))
   {
      trace("poor toad :(");
   }

}
```

Comment: Their already on the stage and they both have their own class.

Comment: Okay well did Nicolas method work for you? Also you might want to look into adding them on the stage via stage.addchild(); and positions makes everything a lot cleaner.